# Moving on after "password and re-typed password" verification

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing an application on “password and re-typed password” verifying routine.

After the [submit] of the necessary details, the function “check_Password(form)” is activated.

If (not …) then {…}.

If (true), {show “ok” via window.alert() with a ‘true’ returned value.}

Then, I want to move on to the next stage by saying

`<a href="mainmenu.html" onClick="checkPassword()">Move on the next stage</a>`

However, the last statement is always on even before the test. How can I hide it and show it only when the verification is ok.

---

[Added]

````
<script>
        function myFunction() 
            {location.replace("http://.../index.html")}
</script>
<button onClick="myFunction()">Re-direction</button>```
````

Comment: Please show your attempt with your code.

Comment: @Newbee See the newly added part and also the comment that I made in below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the question.

Maybe you are looking for something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#rpw').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
          $('#btn').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
          $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);
    })
    $("#btn").click(function(){
      $("#pw").val() == $("#rpw").val() ?
      (window.alert('Successful!'), 
      $("#moveToNext").css("display", "block"))
      : (window.alert('Password not match!'),
      $("#moveToNext").css("display", "none"))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<label>Password: </label><input id="pw" type="password">
<br>
<label>Re-type Password: </label><input id="rpw" type="password">
<br>
<button id="btn">Check</button>
<div style="display:none;" id="moveToNext">
  <a href="mainmenu.html" onClick="checkPassword()">Move on the next stage</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is what I want. Like!

Answer (score 1):

I think to resolve this issue what you can do is initially hide the `anchor tag` and dynamically trigger it based on your verification process success or failure like this:

**Html:**

```
<!-- Add a placeholder element for the statement -->
<div id="next-stage" style="display: none;">
  <a href="mainmenu.html">Move on to the next stage</a>
</div>

<!-- Add a button to trigger the password verification -->
<button onclick="checkPassword()">Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript:**
On the function side of things given that you already have the logic to verify the integrity of the password, you can do something like this:

**Note:** **Just keep in mind that the password verification is hardcoded by me to test the logic in the below snippet, u might need to write your own logic based on the use case.**

```js
function checkPassword() {
  // Perform the password verification
  var isPasswordValid =true // Your password verification logic here

  if (isPasswordValid) {
    // Show the next stage statement
    document.getElementById("next-stage").style.display = "block";
    window.alert("Password verification successful!");
  } else {
    window.alert("Password verification failed!");
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Add a placeholder element for the statement -->
<div id="next-stage" style="display: none;">
  <a href="mainmenu.html">Move on to the next stage</a>
</div>

<!-- Add a button to trigger the password verification -->
<button onclick="checkPassword()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I don't know why your snippet runs ok under this enviroment but not under mine. I found a substitute. (See the 'added' part.) There is still a slight problem: The <button> is always shown. What I want is: Show the <button> only after the validation is complete. Can you help?